# If $A,B$ are homotopic equivalent, $C$ is any topological space then $[A,C]= [B,C]$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Notation:**
$[A,C]= $ Set of homotopy classes of maps $A\to C$

**Claim:** If $A,B$ are homotopy equivalent spaces, $C$ is any topological space then $[A,C]$= $ [B,C]$

**My attempt at a proof:**

Suppose that $[h]\in [A,C]$ (where $[h]$ denotes a homotopy class of maps), so that $h:A\to C$ is a continous map.

$A,B$ being homotopy equivalent that means $\exists f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to identity on $B$ and 
$g\circ f$ is homotopic to identity on $A$.

Then $h\circ g:B\to C$ and $(h\circ g)\circ f \simeq h$

I could not able to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not true that $[A,C]=[B,C]$. On the other hand, what is true is that there is a bijection between the sets $[A,C]$ and $[B,C]$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $h\mapsto h\circ g$ in one direction and $h\mapsto h\circ f$ in the other : can you prove that they're inverse binections ?